# Java zip.close() hangs

Tags: java, scala, zip, inputstream

I am trying to add two small files to a zip, as that is the format the destination requires. Both files are less than 1000kb but when I run my code, the program hangs indefinitely during zip.close(), no errors.
What am I doing wrong?

```
val is = new PipedInputStream()
val os = new PipedOutputStream(is)
val cos = new CountingOutputStream(os)
val zip = new ZipOutputStream(cos)

val fis = new FileInputStream(file)
zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(location))
var i = 0
while(i != -1) {
  zip.write(i)
  i = fis.read()
}
zip.closeEntry()
fis.close()
zip.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using piped streams, you need to read from the `PipedInputStream` at the same time you're writing to a `PipedOutputStream`, otherwise the pipe fills up and the writing will block.

Based on your code, you're not doing the reading part (in a separate thread of course). You can test it with a `FileOutputStream`, and it should write the file nicely.